# View my site in ie6 with a Mac

Tags: internet-explorer, web

How do I go about doing this on a mac?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to ask [browsershots.org](http://browsershots.org/) to take some screenshots of your website on IE6, but you might have to wait every time you want a shot.

The harder ways are to use Boot Camp or a virtual machine like Parallels to run Windows XP with IE6 or attempt use [WineBottler](http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/) to run IE6 without Windows.

Comment: It'll either work fine or not work at all, although since I imagine IE6 would be one of the main use cases, someone will have figured out how to make it work.

Comment: "It'll either work fine or not work at all" : When I tried IE6 on Wine on Linux, it did work, but not fine. Fonts and stuff were all funky, and that is important when looking at how a web site renders.

Comment: @Thilo I don't remember having such issues with IE6 and WineBottler, but I guess it's better to say YMMV.

Answer (score 3):

Virtualization is the best - create VM's for each OS and browser you'd like to test.